# Intuition behind $\arcsin,\arccos,\arctan$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

I'm struggling to grasp intuition behind arc function. I know that it is a inverse function to corresponding trigonometric function ($\sin,\cos...$).
Why their graph looks like it does?

Comment: Consider the graph of the sin function, mapping angles to numbers: "rotate" it and you get the graph of the function mapping numbers to angles. This is the *inverse* function. The definition makes explicit this simple representation.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general answer for that (see the picture below): if you know the graph of $f$, then the graph of $f^{-1}$ is that of $f$ reflected about the line $y=x$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: I'm glad I could help.